# ng-model not updating value with textbox

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox with ng-model binding,I'm entering a value with left space(4 or 5 spaces) and changing  ng-model value with ng-click. But left space is still present in textbox. I have to use jquery trim to remove left empty space . how to do it in angular. why textbox value not changing 
here is the plunker

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <button ng-click="save();">Save</button>
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    after save:{{savedName}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.save=function(){
      $scope.name=$scope.name.trim();
      $scope.savedName=$scope.name.trim();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[here is plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4PCytykzKzVvsWCdEKKs?p=preview)

Comment: hey did you check the demo?

Comment: Yeah. It was working but I forgot to remove  $scope.name="              withleftspace"  while posting .as per my requirement name should be dynamic.I updated my post please look into new plunker

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo with sope.name.trim.

Comment: sorry about that but It was not working though I corrected typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Typo error in $scope

Change

**FROM**

```
$scope.name=$sope.name.trim();
```

**TO**

```
 $scope.name=$scope.name.trim();
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/SIpSSybWXfiz6SsSie6H?p=preview)**

**UPDATE:**
You need to set [`ngTrim`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D) to false. By default Angular sets it to true,

```
<input ng-model="name" ng-trim="false" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/u7ogtmrh/)**

Comment: sorry about that but It was not working though I corrected typo error .forgot to remove name assignment in controller.

Comment: @DasaradhaNimmala did you check the demo i atached?

Comment: Yeah. It was working but I forgot to remove  $scope.name="              withleftspace"; while posting .name should be dynamic.I updated my post.